# Cannot edit sign - Bukkit: org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'sign' in plugin X

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am new to bukkit/spigot and I was making a plugin in which the player could type the command '/sign' and a sign attached to a wooden block will be created next to the player. The sign will display 'Hello *PlayerName*'. However, I got the error: `org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'sign' in plugin`.

Here is a part of my code:

```
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sign") && sender instanceof Player){

        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Location location = player.getLocation();
        World someWorld = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world");

        double playerx = location.getX();
        double playery = location.getY();
        double playerz = location.getZ();

        int px = (int)playerx;
        int py = (int)playery;
        int pz = (int)playerz;

        Location nLoc = new Location(someWorld, px+2, py+1, pz);

        Location sLoc = new Location(someWorld, px+1, py+1, pz);


        Block block = someWorld.getBlockAt(nLoc);
        block.setType(Material.WOOD);

        Block block1 = someWorld.getBlockAt(sLoc);
        block1.setType(Material.SIGN);
        Sign sign = (Sign) block1.getState();
        sign.setLine(0, "Hello\n"+player.getName());




    }
```

How can I fix this error?

The complete error I got on the console was:

```
[17:46:00 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'sign' in plugin FirstPlugin v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:645) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1350) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1185) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_71]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:721) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:660) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:559) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.block.CraftBlockState cannot be cast to org.bukkit.block.Sign
        at zak.firstplugin.FirstPlugin.onCommand(FirstPlugin.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-d20369f-7fc5cd8]
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast a `BlockState` of a `Block` to a subclass of which it is not an instance, this error (like in your stack trace) is thrown: `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.[version].block.CraftBlockState cannot be cast to org.bukkit.block.[YourState]`. In other words, your code is throwing that error because the block isn't actually a `Sign`, as in it's `BlockState` is not an instance of a `Sign`. In the future, you can always check using `instanceof` to make sure a superclass can be cast to a specific subclass:

```
if (block.getState() instanceof Sign) {
    Sign sign = (Sign) block.getState();
    // ... Your code
}
```

The reason your block is not a sign even though you set its material to `Material.SIGN`, is that the `Material.SIGN` enumerator actually refers to the sign *item* type, not the *block* type, of which there are actually two (`Material.SIGN_POST` and `Material.WALL_SIGN`). Confusingly, Bukkit/Spigot doesn't warn you when you set a `Block`'s type to that of an item type, and instead sets the `Block`'s type or material to air (and thus the `ClassCastException` is thrown). I'm guessing that since you are spawning a solid block for the sign, you probably want the latter enumerator or `Material.WALL_SIGN`.

Also, to make sure the text on the sign appears, you'll need to update the BlockState using `state.update()` (and possibly even force update using `state.update(true)`).

To write the player's name on the next line, you'll need to add that `String` to line 2 (index 1) using `sign.setLine(1, player.getName())`, not using the `\n` newline character, which Minecraft signs don't handle.

Last but not least, the wall sign in your case will be facing the wrong way, which can be fixed by changing the sign's rotation. This depends on where the wooden block is placed in relation to the sign of course, so in your case the sign would need to be rotated to face west. To set the sign's rotation we could use the deprecated `setData(byte data)` method for `Block`s, but if you want to do it the non-deprecated, more easily readable way, we'll have to deal with another small quirk: There is an `org.bukkit.block.Sign` *interface*, and an `org.bukkit.material.Sign` *class*. All usages of `Sign` above refer to the `org.bukkit.block.Sign` interface which is a subtype of `BlockState`. This is used to for example set the sign's text. `org.bukkit.material.Sign` is a subtype of the `MaterialData` class which we can access using `state.getData()` and is used to change the direction of the sign because that class implements the `Directional` interface (specifically the `Attachable` interface). So to set the text *and* rotate the sign, we'll have to use both the class and interface. Here is some example code:

```
Block sign = world.getBlockAt(signLoc); // Get the block
sign.setType(Material.WALL_SIGN); // Set the type to "WALL_SIGN", now it's BlockState is an instance of "Sign"

BlockState signState = sign.getState(); // Get the general state

if (signState instanceof org.bukkit.block.Sign) { // Make sure the sign block really does have the "Sign" BlockState (this isn't really necessary, more of a double check)
    org.bukkit.block.Sign signBlock = (org.bukkit.block.Sign) signState; // Note that this is the org.bukkit.block.Sign interface
    signBlock.setLine(0, "Hello"); // Set the first line
    signBlock.setLine(1, player.getName()); // Set the second line
    if (signState.getData() instanceof org.bukkit.material.Sign) { // Now get the "MaterialData" from the BlockState...
        org.bukkit.material.Sign signMaterialData = (org.bukkit.material.Sign) signState.getData(); // And cast it to org.bukkit.material.Sign
        signMaterialData.setFacingDirection(BlockFace.WEST); // Use this to change the direction of the sign, in this case WEST (sign is placed + X direction of player)
    }
    signBlock.update(); // Update the sign's state
}
```